# How to check if a user is a member within an organisation within a members RLS policy with Supabase

Tags: postgresql, supabase, row-level-security, supabase-database

I'm trying to write a SELECT RLS policy for a members table within Supabase. The policy should only reveal members that are in the same organisations as you.

Each row in the members table represents a membership to an organisation and a user should only be able to view members that are in the same organisation as them.

I've tried a number of different strategies however I'm having a problem with recursion.

Here's the basic table setup:

organisations: an entity which users can be a part of
members: each row represents a membership to an organisation (a user can be in multiple orgs)

Fields of note on members:
members.organisation links to the org this member is a part of
members.user links to the user that is associated with this membership

If anyone can give me pointers or just flat out tell me my DB architecture is wrong it would be much appreciated. I understand I haven't probably asked the best question with all the info needed but I'm not very good when it comes to SQL databases.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I would recommend using [custom claims](https://blog.mansueli.com/using-custom-claims-testing-rls-with-supabase). If you want to have this automatically handled for you, then you can set up [triggers to manage the relationships](https://blog.mansueli.com/using-triggers-to-map-database-relationships-in-custom-claims).